# What are some ways to securing web api with authorization in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, microsoft-identity-platform

I am developing an Web API .net core and hosting it in Azure as we are migrating to Azure. To secure the web API and for Authorization (Protect a web API backend in Azure API Management using OAuth 2.0 authorization with Azure Active Directory). But I have some questions as following below:

Question 1. if I protect a web API backend in Azure API Management using OAuth 2.0 authorization with Azure Active Directory then if we want to expose the Api to the third party outside of the organization then would it work?

Questions 2 Can we protect an Api that is hosting in  OAuth without Active Directory.

Question 3.  What is securing an api with Microsoft Identity vs OAuth. It is confusing to me why should I not use Microsoft identity over OAuth for Authorization. Is it something new that came out from Microsoft?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-web-api

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I protect a web API backend in Azure API Management using OAuth 2.0 authorization with Azure Active Directory then if we want to expose the Api to the third party outside of the organization then would it work?

If your protecting your web API backend in Azure API Management using OAuth 2.0 authorization with Azure Active Directory, you cannot expose your API to any 3rd party application  or an organization so easily.

For that purpose you will have to
federate that application/SAAS with azure AD for users in that platform to be able to access the API.

You have to give permission/privileges to the federated users of that platform to be able to access the web API and its scope.

> Can we protect an Api that is hosting in OAuth without Active Directory?

No, we cannot protect an API hosting in OAuth without Active Directory.

Because, OAuth authorization code grant can be used in apps that are installed on a device to gain access to protected resources, such as web APIs.
It's used to perform authentication and authorization in the majority of app types, including web apps and natively installed apps.

> What is securing an api with Microsoft Identity vs OAuth?

A **managed identity** generated by Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) allows your API Management instance to easily and securely access other Azure AD-protected resources, such as Azure Key Vault.